# Homophone Riddle 12

Tags: riddle, word

I overheard Riddler Rick, muttering to himself. I decided to write it down, so what was he trying to tell?

```
Money and its simile
The answer to it all
The first word belongs to money
The second, money’s simile 
The words are both verbs
They are homophones, after all
```

If you are not familiar with Homophone Riddles, check out 1-11.

Hint 1:

> Try to find "money's simile" first.

Hint 2:

> The word sizes for each homophone are 4 letters and 5 letters.

Comment: rot13(Abg ernyyl fher vs V'z ba gur evtug genpx, orpnhfr V pna'g svaq nal ubzbalzf bs SNK (snpfvzvyr), ohg snk *vf* n ireo)

Comment: @Avi Rot13 (Gel gb svaq n fvzvyr jvgu zbarl, gura gur ubzbcubarf fubhyq or cerggl rnfl gb svaq.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is money's simile bread? Need/Knead.

Comment: The answer is correct, but bread is supposed to be dough. Money => Dough. +1 and check :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> **cash/cache**. A cache of cash would certainly answer a lot of questions, both words can be verbs.

Comment: I know I keep saying this but try to find money's (figurative) simile. Then the homophone should become clearer. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be

> Dye/Die

Money and its simile

> "nothing can be said to be certain, except death and taxes." - Benjamin Franklin.
>  In this way, to die is a simile for paying money in that they are both certainties.

The answer to it all

> The two certainties.

The first word belongs to money

> I think this refers either to the dye used to print paper money or possibly [dye packs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye_pack) used to protect currency.

The second, money’s simile

> Die, as explained above.

The words are both verbs

> Die and dye are both verbs (dye is also a noun).

They are homophones, after all

> Die and dye are pronounced the same.

Comment: Not correct, but here's another hint, when finding money's simile, try to think figuratively.